# MVC : try to Display a user control bind to a controller, on a JQuery Dialog has no result

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-ui-dialog, user-controls

HI. 
This my problem. 
I have a form, which need to display a form (coming from a user control already done).

This is the code :

```
<%@ Register src="~/Views/MyView.ascx" tagname="ViewToDisplay" tagprefix="uc1" %>

    <script >
            $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
            $(function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "explode",
                    modal: true
                });
                $("#opener").click(function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                    return false;
                });
            });
    </script>

(... code)
<div id="dialog">
   <h3>Contain of my UC</h3> 
   <uc1:MyView ID="MyView1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Open my UC in my dialog modal

But when I click on my button "opener", nothing happened. 
Even if I just put 'hello world' in my UC (which is in the same folder than the current Page).
However, if I remove the line "", the modal popup is normally displayed.

Any idea, why I cant display the uc1 on my jQuery Dialog box ??

Edited part :

This part of code is not working (no display of a dialog)

```
<html>
 <%@ Register src="~/Views/MyView.ascx" tagname="ViewToDisplay" tagprefix="uc1" %>

        <script >
                $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
                $(function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        show: "blind",
                        hide: "explode",
                        modal: true
                    });
                    $("#opener").click(function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                        return false;
                    });
                });
        </script>

    <div id="dialog">
       <h3>Contain of my UC</h3> 
       <uc1:MyView ID="MyView1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</html>
```

This part of code is working : (I removed the include of my uc1 in my dialog)

```
<html>
     <%@ Register src="~/Views/MyView.ascx" tagname="ViewToDisplay" tagprefix="uc1" %>

            <script >
                    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
                    $(function() {
                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            show: "blind",
                            hide: "explode",
                            modal: true
                        });
                        $("#opener").click(function() {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
            </script>

        <div id="dialog">
           <h3>Contain of my UC</h3> 
              Im the king of the world without my dialog box...
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you remove which line it works? all I see above is "" remember you can't paste html directly in there it needs to be html encoded to show properly on stack overflow

Comment: @Adam : I posted again my question, splitting the working code and the failed code.

Comment: post the code that &ltuc1:MyView ID="MyView1" runat="server" /%gt;  generates - IE browser - view source.

Comment: Well I finally find the solution to my problem : it was only a problem of redunding JQuery declaration code, present in the main form, and in the UserControl called...

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally find the solution to my problem : it was only a problem of redunding JQuery declaration code, present in the main form, and in the UserControl called...